# How do you determine what technology a website is built on?

Tags: html, frameworks, reverse-engineering

Quite often I come across a nice looking or functional website, and wonder what technology was used to create it. What techniques are available to figure out what a
particular website was built with?

Few frameworks seem to include any kind of generator meta tag like web editors do. Are there any tell-tale signs of particular languages and/or frameworks?

---

***Summary of answers***

Site URLs may betray the framework and/or programming language but cannot be relied upon (e.g. file extensions such as .asp). HTTP response headers, cookies, stylesheets and source comments may also give clues.

Some nice tools for querying site details (no doubt there are many more):

- [BuiltWith](http://builtwith.com/)
- [DomainTools](http://www.domaintools.com/)
- [NetCraft](http://news.netcraft.com/)
- [W3Techs](http://w3techs.com/sites)
- [SimilarTech](http://www.similartech.com)

Firefox addons:

- [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/) - CMS, frameworks/libraries, e-commerce, message boards etc.
- [Domain Details](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2166) - IP, country and webserver details
- [Library Detector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10083) - Javascript libraries in use

Chrome Extensions:

- [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com/)
- [SimilarTech](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/similartech-site-technolo/jiabgmelnfhgjkfdaoiccfcbaedjfcnm)
- [PageXray](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagexray/aedmpdookgbneegaeajpoldpnpfbpmlb)

Bookmarklets:

- [WTFramework](http://blog.olicio.us/2008/11/08/wtframework-bookmarklet/) - shows Javascript framework in use

Comment: I like to use [Wappalyzer](http://wappalyzer.com), a Firefox add-on, to see at a glance the site's technologies.

Comment: http://guess.scritch.org/ is also a decent tool for querying site details.

Comment: I would love to know if its a way to hide the underlying server language

Comment: @shababhsiddique The underlying server language is "hidden" by default. There won't be any standard technique for hiding what your site is built on - just don't let your Backend output any tell-tale markers to the front end

Comment: @ZachL still I found a few websites in the past that I couldnt tell was built with. take apple.com for instance. http://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fwww.apple.com%2f , how do you find out? if you cant find out how did apple hid it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are all sorts of things you can look out for, but it doesn't really give you any certainty as to the technology behind a site. In general, information like that is something people will want to hide, as the more information that is exposed the easier it might be for malicious parties to identify security vulnerabilities or denial of service holes.

If I was interested I'd probably look, in no particular order, at:

- urls, and file extensions.
- HTTP response headers
- Source code for comments, or standard JS libraries

Incidentally, the tools mentioned in other answers are only looking at some of the above properties of the site for you, albeit automatically, and slightly quicker. :)

Comment: There were lots of good answers so I've somewhat delayed choosing an accepted one, but this fitted best. It covers the basic starting points to use perhaps before delving for automated tools.

Answer (score 67):

You could use http://builtwith.com to figure out which server and programming language was used. For example it told me that SO uses IIS7, google analytics, html4 and utf8.

If you want to know the framework...well that will probably not be possible just from looking at the site. Why don't you write them an email? ;)

Comment: Write them an email, well that's lateral thinking for you. Good point! And I like builtwith.com, just need some way to bookmark this answer. Cheers.

Comment: Built with cant tell SO is on IIS7 how did you get that info?

Comment: @shababhsiddique: Back in 2008 it could.

Comment: How can I hide my sites info as well? I havent seen any resource yet?

Comment: @shababhsiddique: that is a separate question, you should ask it properly if it doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 8):

I use 1 plug in for Firefox that gives me the IP and country for the hosting website and it's Web Server name called [Domain Details](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2166), and for javascript framework I use [WTFramework](http://blog.olicio.us/2008/11/08/wtframework-bookmarklet/)

I still need to wonder what script it was written on, but it is a start :)

Hope it helps.

P.S. the output will be something like this:

[alt text http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2505/200812282328ha0.png](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/2505/200812282328ha0.png)

Comment: glad you liked it :) you can also click the "correct icon" that is bellow the reputaion number for this question so you can mark it as an accepted answer if you wanted ;)

Comment: Any chance you know of a Domain Details Extension for Chrome?

Comment: @Andrew did at least try to find it out? it's the first result I get searching on Google!

Answer (score 6):

URLs can give a lot of clues, especially with Content Management Systems.

For example "http://abcxyz.com/**node/46**" looks a lot like Drupal.

Also many frameworks have standard JavaScript and CSS files they use.

Comment: Nice! I like the standard javascript and particularly standard CSS files as a fingerprint.

Comment: Incorrect. SO uses .NET and has a syntax similar to your example. A website I developed uses the same syntax and runs on Django.

Comment: Same patter of url is used by Rails as well ... For Rails application. You can see same format. For eg : http://mysite.com/post/12

Answer (score 4):

Some people might even deliberately obscure the technology they use. After all, it wouldn't take me long to tweak apache so that ".asp" actually ran perl scripts and put "powered by Microsoft IIS" into my footer despite the fact I used MySQL.

That way you'd spend all your time trying to hack my site using vulnerabilities it doesn't actually have.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Chrome Sniffer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae), a great light-weight solution.

Comment: Nice chrome extension, as of 2014, it gives you a very complete info of the technical stack. This works great with the BuiltWith extension (the last one gives you more network-related info)

Answer (score 3):

Examining the cookies the site gives can reveal the underlying framework.  CodeIgniter, for example defaults to a telltale ci_sessions cookie.  Sites using PEAR Auth will do something similar.

Answer (score 3):

I use WebParser (http://www.cybermake.com) that allows to determine the CMS used by a website. It allows to determine CMS for multiple websites as well as it can pull the list of websites from the search engines for a given list of keywords. Powerful tool.

Answer (score 3):

http://guess.scritch.org/ does this for CMSs.

Just pop in the URL and it'll try to guess the CMS. In this case it tells me my blog is running wordpress 3.4.2 (which is correct, I just checked!)

[image]

Comment: It's not good. Only reads page metatags... :(

Answer (score 2):

Most ASP.NET sites are easy to identify from the .aspx in the URLs. There are also telltale signs in the HTML source, like a hidden form field named `__VIEWSTATE` or the WebResource.axd JavaScript. HTML elements will often have id attributes starting with something like `_ctl0`.

Rails sites will usually include stylesheets from /stylesheets and JavaScript files from /javascripts and each URL will usually have a query string containing a timestamp to thwart caching. Form fields will often follow the naming convention of `model_name[attribute_name]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use http://builtbased.com/ to figure out which server, framework and programming language was used.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.similartech.com is a new tool we made, that does just that and presents it very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use domaintools.com to lookup the server information for a website and narrow down to whether it's open source / Microsoft:

http://whois.domaintools.com/stackoverflow.com

And after that it's a matter of looking in the footer for tip-offs such as "Powered by WordPress" or "vBulletin"  etc.

Comment: Another cool tool I need to find a way to bookmark within SO. I'll have to add these links to the quesion.

Answer (score 1):

yes there are some telltale signs for common CMSs like Drupal, Joomla, Pligg,  and RoR etc ..  .. ASP.NET stuff is easy to spot too .. but as the framework becomes more obscure it gets harder to deduce ..

What I usually is compare the site i am snooping with another site that I know is built using a particular tech. That sometimes works ..

Answer (score 1):

Go to [Netcraft](http://news.netcraft.com/) and use the "What's that site running?" search box in the top left corner. Click here for the report on [Stack Overflow](http://toolbar.netcraft.com/site_report?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com). It won't necessarily be correct (e.g., there could be caching or load balancing in the way), but it often gives you the clue you need.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [W3Techs](http://w3techs.com/sites), which shows you much of that information.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux/OSX I often use simple command `curl -sI www.site.com`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.quarkbase.com/ is a very nice tool and information website