# Check if a webapp has React, Angular or Vue installed

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js

Is there a trivial way to see what client-side libraries an application is using when everything is minified/compressed? I am looking at all of the javascript passed to the client from the server but with everything compressed/minified, I'm not necessarily able to tell if one of the three popular client-side frameworks is used. For jQuery, it's as trivial as doing the following in the console:

```
> jQuery.fn.jquery
"3.2.1"
```

Is there a similar method for checking the other three "big" frameworks?

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using the developer tools of each framework or an extension such as [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en). If you want to detect a framework programatically you could have a peek at the source code of the relevant devtools extension. For example I looked at the Vue devtools [source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/e34da177b909255a46a13667d63681639672c8a3/shells/chrome/src/detector.js#L31-L39) and it looks like you could simply detect Vue like this ..

```
function detectVue() {
    const all = document.querySelectorAll('*')
    for(let i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
        if (all[i].__vue__) return true
    }
    return false
}

detectVue()
```

Answer (score 7):

The easy way I suggest is install the `wappalyzer` extension Click [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

Wappalyzer is a cross-platform utility that uncovers the technologies used on websites.

Below is the live website screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You can add extensions to chrome to check for many libraries, I use react so with [react developers tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) is easy to see a site using it (image below). You can add extensions for [angular](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-state-inspector/nelkodgfpddgpdbcjinaaalphkfffbem?hl=en) an [vue](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) too. Hope it helps.

[image: react developers tool]

Answer (score 2):

Angular will have ng-version attribute in root component

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To check information about the technology stack used by websites. We can make use of [BuildWith](https://builtwith.com/) website.

It allows us to analyze and identify the technologies that power a particular website and provide information about the Web Server, CDN, Frameworks, Analytics and Tracking Tools, JavaScript Libraries, etc used in it.

**Enter the website url**

[image]

Below is the result of the technology stack used by this website.

[image]