# how can we decipher if a site is using angular react or vue?

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js

Just curious offhand if there is an obvious way to detect which of these technologies are used in a site. Looking for those quirks that we can observe certain behaviours that we can identify the technology behind it. Thank you.

Comment: If you install the React Developer addon/extension it will go blue/red if a site is using the react framework/technology otherwise for angular and vue I don't know (they might have an addon/extension as well).

Comment: What quirks? What behaviours? React, Vue, Angular, all of these get converted to vanilla Javascript when built so ultimately by the time it's running in your browser there's no real difference between which technology was used during development

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a webapp has React, Angular or Vue installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879552/check-if-a-webapp-has-react-angular-or-vue-installed)

Answer (score 0):

You can down React Developer Tools extension for chrome [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) . When visiting the website that using React, the extension gets illuminated.

Comment: This isn't really an answer that fully addresses the question(s) by the OP. How does the React dev tool help a person identify SPA's build using Angular or Vue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg?hl=en) to check which JavaScript libraries and frameworks are in use for any web app.

Comment: Welcome ! Can you please mark this answer as correct ?