# how to reverse engineer or get know about the technology being use by a website?

Tags: knowledge-capture

Just for knowledge, I want to know about a site that what technology stack it is using in the product?

Like facebook, linkedin and other giants share tech stack they are using. Curious about learning systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you determine what technology a website is built on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396739/how-do-you-determine-what-technology-a-website-is-built-on)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean you want to know the different programming languages, servers and other technologies they use to develop their website?

If that is the case one way i know is to use the wappalyzer chrome extension.
This gives you a list of the different technologies (like programming languages, servers used, the different analytics it uses, etc. )used to develop that website.

Comment: Thats a comment, not an answer

Comment: I know , but i dint get the privilege to add a comment yet

Comment: @SAIPRATYUSHA, no problem!, yep you get my question, will check with wapplyzer, actually I tried to get the tech for a website I was curious to know about by inspecting through chrome dev tools.

Comment: @SAIPRATYUSHA, good one! but yes I want to know about 3rd party tech used but It not work for that.